# .net web api AuthorizeAttribute pass parameter to the controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, custom-attributes

A AuthorizedAttribute named as JwtAuthenticateAttribute is implemented and did something

It can be triggered for each request of the below API

```
[HttpGet]
[JwtAuthenticate]
public GetFaqListDS Index([FromUri] GetFaqListModel model)
{
    List<MP_faqs> res = Faq.GetFaqList(model.curPage, model.pageSize);
    var re = Request;
    var hds = re.Headers;
    GetFaqListDS ds = new GetFaqListDS();
    ds.data = res;
    return ds;
}
```

The question is, how to pass a value to this controller's function from the Attribute JwtAuthenticate.

P.S the value exists at the OnAuthorization of this attribute.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add the required value in "actionContext.Request.Properties" in Onauthorize method and access these in controller.

Adding UserDetail Model :

```
actionContext.Request.Properties.Add("__user", new UserDetails(){userid=123, username="ABC"});
```

Retrieving values :

```
private static UserDetails GetUserDetailsFromRequest()
    {
        object tempVal;
        try
        {
            var httpRequestMessage = (HttpRequestMessage)HttpContext.Current.Items["MS_HttpRequestMessage"];
            httpRequestMessage.Properties.TryGetValue("__user", out tempVal);
            if (tempVal == null) return null;
            var user = (UserDetails)tempVal;
            return user;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return new UserDetails();
    }
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: thanks, it works, lets wait and see if there is better option:)